# Generating istanbul code coverage reports for jasmine tests run (via grunt) on a browserify bundle in phantomjs

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, phantomjs, browserify, istanbul

The title says it all really. Despite trawling the internet I haven't found a single example of a solution to this problem.

Here are some near misses

- https://github.com/amitayd/grunt-browserify-jasmine-node-example - grunt, browserify and jasmine
- https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul/issues/59#issuecomment-18799734 - browserify and istanbul

Here is my in-progress code https://github.com/wheresrhys/on-guard/tree/browserify (note it's the 'browserify' branch - Gruntfile.js is a bit of a mess but will tidy it up shortly). My initial investigations using `console.log` indicate that somehow `bundle.src.js` is being loaded in the page but when the tests are run (and passed!) the code in `bundle.src.js` isn't being run, so I have a feeling it might be an aliasing problem... though one that's limited to phantomjs as when I open the specrunner in chrome the code is getting run.

Comment: Did you figure this one out? Does it currently work in the on-guard project?

Comment: What does it mean when this question has been here for 3 years with out an answer...

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `grunt-browserify` + `browserify-istanbul` + `grunt-contrib-jasmine` + `grunt-template-jasmine-istanbul` as solution. This solution has also **excluded third party libraries** when building source files using `browserify`.

Show the code first, I'll explain later,

```
grunt.initConfig({
browserify: {
  // build specs using browserify
  specs: {
    src: ["spec/**/*Spec.js"],
    dest: "spec/build/specs.js",
    options: {
      debug: true
    }
  },
  // build source files using browserify and browserify-istanbul
  dev: {
    options: {
      debug: true,
      browserifyOptions: {
        standalone: 'abc'
      },
      transform: [['browserify-istanbul', {
        ignore: ['**/node_modules/**'], // ignore third party libs
        defaultIgnore: true
      }]]
    },
    src: ['abc.js'],
    dest: 'dist/abc.js'
  }
},
connect: {
  server: {
    options: {
      port: 7000
    }
  }
},
// test using jasmine, generate coverage report using istanbul
jasmine: {
  coverage: {
    src: ['dist/abc.js'],
    options: {
      junit: {
            path: 'bin/junit'
        },
      host: 'http://localhost:7000/',
      specs:  'spec/build/specs.js',
      keepRunner: true,
      summary: true,
      template: require('grunt-template-jasmine-istanbul'),
      templateOptions: {
        replace: false, // *** this option is very important
        coverage: 'bin/coverage/coverage.json',
        report: [
          {
          type: 'html',
          options: {
            dir: 'spec/coverage/html'
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  }      
}

  grunt.registerTask('specs', ['browserify:specs', 'browserify:dev', 'connect', 'jasmine']);
```

The steps of generating istanbul coverage report can be concluded into three:

1. Instrument code
2. Run test
3. Generate coverage report

In our solution, we use `browerify-istanbul` in step 1, `grunt-contrib-jasmine` and `runt-template-jasmine-istanbul` in step 2 and 3.

`browserify-istanbul` will let you instrument code in browserify building step, in this way, we can easily ignore third party libs. But the `grunt-template-jasmine-istanbul` will instrument code again. To avoid this, you can set `replace` to `false` in the options.

Refs:

1. [Istanbul steps](https://blog.engineyard.com/2015/measuring-clientside-javascript-test-coverage-with-istanbul)
2. [broswerify-istanbul](https://github.com/devongovett/browserify-istanbul)
3. [grunt-contrib-jasmine](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jasmine)
4. [grunt-template-jasmine-istanbul](https://github.com/maenu/grunt-template-jasmine-istanbul) -- `replace` option